# Cannot upgrade or otherwise change tex-live installation on Heroku

Tags: heroku, tex-live

Pushes of updates to my app to Heroku are now rejected because of a tex-live incompatibility.  See the error message below.

**Heroku error message**

```
remote: tlmgr: Remote repository is newer than local (2018 < 2019)
remote: Cross release updates are only supported with
remote:   update-tlmgr-latest(.sh/.exe) --update
remote: Please see https://tug.org/texlive/upgrade.html for 
details.
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile TeX Live app.
```

I have tried the following:

1. Add a file `texlive.repository` with contents `ftp://tug.org/historic/systems/texlive/2018/tlnet-final`.  This does not work because the texlive repository lacks a required cryptographic certificate.
2. Delete the texlive buildpack and start over.  Below is my buildpack config. However, when I try to remove it, I get this message:

   $ heroku buildpacks:remove syphar/heroku-buildpack-tex
   ›   Error: invalid json response body at https://buildpack-registry.heroku.com/buildpacks/syphar%2Fheroku-buildpack-tex reason: Unexpected end of JSON input

At this point I am stuck!

**Heroku buildpacks**

```
$ heroku buildpacks
=== nshost Buildpack URLs
1. https://github.com/HashNuke/heroku-buildpack-elixir.git
2. https://github.com/syphar/heroku-buildpack-tex.git
```

Answer (score 1):

This works: in the file texlive.packages, replace

```
ftp://tug.org/historic/systems/texlive/2018/tlnet-final
```

with

```
https://www.math.utah.edu/pub/texlive/historic/systems/texlive/2018/tlnet-final
```

Solution courtesy of Nelson Beebe, University of Utah Mathematics Department